# Quotient of quotient groups and Sylow $p$-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Let $\pi:G\rightarrow G/N$ be the canonical homomorphism.

Suppose $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then $\pi[P]\leq G/N$. Note that $G$ operates transitively on $(G/N)/\pi[P]$. Therefore there exists a subgroup $S$ of $G$ such that $[G:S]=\left[G/N:\pi[P]\right]$.

It is claimed that $P\subset S$. I don't know why this holds. Hints?

Let $f:G/S\rightarrow (G/N)/\pi[P]$ be the $G$-isomorphism mentioned. I know that $f(S)=\pi[P]$. This implies that $P=\pi^{-1}[f(S)]$.

**Edit:**

I think I have to pick $S:=\text{stab}_{G}(\pi[P])$ for this to work, since $P\subset\text{stab}_{G}(\pi[P])$.

Comment: You could take $S=PN$, since the canonical image of $P$ under $\pi$ Is $PN/N$.

Comment: I was hoping to obtain $S$ by merely invoking the fundamental theorem of group actions (since $G$ operates transitively on $(G/N)/\pi[P]$). But I guess that won't be enough.

Comment: Yes, $S:=\text{stab}_{G}(\pi[P])$ does the trick. This $S$ is also equal to $PN$.